# C to shellcode conversion

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, shellforge

I am trying to convert C code into shell code using `shellforge` so I have extracted the `shellforge`, but when I am trying to do conversion using

```
./sf.py examples/hello.c
```

I am getting error-

```
##[ERROR]## compiler reported error 127 while compiling /tmp/sfIKzb4Y/hello.c
##[ERROR]## sh: 1: gcc34: not found
```

and I tried to find solution but I didn't find it anywhere. Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The script is trying to call a compiler called `gcc34`.  This compiler is not installed on your system.

Two solutions:

1. Install the required compiler.
2. Make the script pick a compiler that *is* installed on the system.

Since I'm unfamiliar with Ubuntu, I can't help you with the first one, and since I've never heard of this script, I can't help you with the second one. Sorry.